# How to show data from DB and Website crawl on same search page [browse] in different panels

Tags: solr

Currently I am crawling the Website data and DB data in my Solr Index. However on search page I have 2 panels:
1) Panel A showing results coming from DB
2) Panel B showing results coming from Website crawl

I am unable to understand how I should fire 2 queries to Index 1 for DB and 2nd for Webcrawl data.

Problem I am facing is: only one query is getting fired on index. 
When I fires a query suppose 35 results are returned by index. (20 for DB and 10 for Web) 
But on page 1: out of 10 results if 6 results are of web and 4 results are of DB then

Panel A shows 4 results
Panle B shows 6 results

I want both these Panels have individual results set

Comment: Hmm did not really understand your question. If you need 2 indexes than create 2 separate solr indexes and send queries at the same time to them?

Comment: I am only referring to 1 index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are facing problem in differentiating documents from DB and website then one thing you can do is, Make one extra field in your solr document e.g "source" and put value in this field at index time according to source of that document. i.e DB or website

Later you can fire filter query on index and get documents only from that source.
      e.g : source:DB "sample query" 
Above query will bring all documents matching "sample query" and having source as DB.

Comment: Hi NutchUser,
Yes, For DB source I am doing the same thing source:DB however i am unable to add extra field for Web Crawl.

Could you be able to help me n this part with some example?

Comment: How are you crawling ? are you using Nutch or other crawler to crawl website? And If you are already having "source" field created then you need to just put value in that field.

Comment: I am using Nutch crawler and using following command:
bin/nutch crawl urls -solr http://localhost:8983/solr/ -depth 1 -topN 20
How to put value "webcrawl" in source feild for webcrawl?

Comment: You may need to modify this http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/nutch/nutch-1.2/org/apache/nutch/indexer/basic/BasicIndexingFilter.java.html

Comment: Thanks NutchUser For your answer.